# Redirect Active Admin login to Devise Login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, devise, activeadmin

In my App I have successfully installed Devise and it works perfectly nice. Then I have first time installed **[Active Admin](http://activeadmin.info/documentation.html)** for Admin panel and have set path. Now when I try to login in Active Admin `localhost:3000/admin/login` it redirect me to *Devise's login page*. I know there may be silly mistake but not aware how to solve this issue??

**app/config/initializers/active_admin.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|  #I have removed comments
 config.site_title = "Shopaholic"
 config.authentication_method = :authenticate_admin_user!
 config.current_user_method = :current_admin_user
 config.logout_link_path = :destroy_admin_user_session_path
 config.batch_actions = true
end
```

**app/config/initializers/devise.rb**

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.secret_key = '28c01a5ccf820bb594d2b6421becfa6487df79dad52a57d49cf61f802ea00c7364215f43cdf87463503e658da69e182f8c35d668577f975fea2bdee736a5d20a'
  config.mailer_sender = 'please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com'
  require 'devise/orm/active_record'
  config.authentication_keys = [ :email ]
  config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :email ]
  config.strip_whitespace_keys = [ :email ]
  config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]
  config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 10
  config.remember_for = 2.weeks
  config.password_length = 8..128
  config.reset_password_within = 6.hours
  config.default_scope = :users
  config.sign_out_via = :delete
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Shopaholic::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => "products#products_list"
  #root to: "admin/dashboard#index"
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

  devise_for :users
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
end
```

If you required any further information then let me know I will Update. Please help me to solve this issue.. Thanks in advance

Comment: It's the error because of the active admin also use devise gem for user authentication and i think you have installed both devise(first) and active admin(second).

Comment: @Bharatsoni : Yes I have first installed Devise then Active Admin but now how to solve it???

Comment: @Bharatsoni : In my database there are two tables `admin_users` for active admin and `users` for devise.

Comment: I thing if you have just created a new application then create a new app and do not install devise and directly go to active admin.

Comment: @Bharatsoni : No I have completed my app for e-commerce.

Comment: if ur purpose is generic and only to monitor certain aspects of ur app, u can be an admin using just devise. - https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-an-Admin-role   .....  and  http://rubyonrailshelp.wordpress.com/2014/01/03/creating-user-and-admin-model-using-devise-rails/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think If you have this block in application_controller.rb then it will redirect you to Devise's login page:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    users_path
end
```

To resolve this redirection use this block instead of above block:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if resource.is_a?(AdminUser)
        admin_dashboard_path
    else
        users_path
    end
end
```

And if you have still issue due to "before_action :authenticate_user!" this on application_controller.rb then as per @YodaTravis use this block in bottom of config/initializers/active_admin.rb

```
ActiveAdmin::BaseController.class_eval do
    skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!
end
```

It will work for you!!

Answer (score 6):

in your

```
config/initializers/active_admin.rb
```

add the following to the bottom of the setup block

```
ActiveAdmin::BaseController.class_eval do
  skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!
end
```

UPDATE: with Rails 5.0 and higher you'll want to add it like this:

```
config.skip_before_action :authenticate_user!
```

Answer (score 0):

The files should be in config/initializers rather than app/initializers (see: config/initializers/active_admin.rb).

BTW, I would recommend adding an admin column to your devise model and using it for authenticating admin users that can access active_admin.

Comment: YEs file is in already in config/intializers. It was my mistake to put the path. I have updated it. Tnx for your answer. But issue is redirection, does it solve the problem??